# Task, CodedUI, and Clipboard errors

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, clipboard, coded-ui-tests

I am updating a CodedUI test program. Part of the update I have been working on is threading the test so that I can cancel the test, when necessary, without needing to kill the test program. The Task I create works fine until the CodedUI test copies data to the Clipboard then tries to retrieve that so it can dump it to a database. Without the task, this works with no issues, but with the task, `Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text)` returns null.

Because `Keyboard.SendKeys` is used before the Clipboard request, I tried [CodedUI Test: Keyboard.SendKeys not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014218/codedui-test-keyboard-sendkeys-not-working) to see if that would help, but it did not.

Comment: Can't you write to the database directly? if not there are several ways to wait on an aysnc operation. you might need to wait until it finishes. Often the wait has a timeout as well.

Comment: @RyanBurnham - I do not work on the tested program. It appears as though the command to write to the Clipboard was designed specifically for QA testing as I can see no reason for the users to have need for that information (it's a customer service program used in call centers). The tested program itself connects to a separate database for its own information. For the CodedUI action, it runs the `Keyboard.SendKeys`, waits for 10 seconds, then calls `Clipboard.GetData` and processes what it needs from the data.

Comment: My guess is its a threading issue, the background thread can't access the clipboard content of anther thread. I found something that might be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635994/getting-data-off-the-clipboard-inside-a-backgroundworker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Getting data off the Clipboard inside a BackgroundWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635994/getting-data-off-the-clipboard-inside-a-backgroundworker) solved the issue. Though nothing threw errors relating to the Thread Apartment State, setting it to STA makes things work.